# Visualize hierarchical / tree data where each node may have more than one parent in R or python

Tags: python, r, tree, many-to-many, hierarchical-data

I'm looking for a way to visualize hierarchical data where there is a many to many relationship between parent and child - this is not a tree, but should be hierarchical like a tree. Is there a good package in R for doing this? I've looked at a few but they're either for visualizing trees or for visualizing graphs, but I'd like to visualize a graph that is also hierarchical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to visualise a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG).  I.e. there are no cycles but each node may have multiple in-degree and out-degree.  Graph libraries will usually visualise these correctly if you set the right parameters.  I would recommend networkx  for small/medium-sized graphs, or Gephi for large graphs (gephi is a GUI program but makes good visualisations).  Networkx's Graphviz drawing backend will do a good job of drawing DAGs

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.dag.html
http://gephi.github.io/

Comment: Thanks Stephen! that sounds good. What is a small/medium-sized graph? I'm thinking there may be thousands of nodes total - a couple hundred at each level, 7-10 levels

Comment: also there is a rgraphviz in R, are there any relations between rgraphviz and graphviz?

Comment: Graphviz is a set of unix tools that layount and render graphs.  rgraphviz is an R binding to graphviz and there are a couple of Python bindings (used by networkx).  You can use graphviz on it's own as it has a plain-text input format.

Comment: I'd say you have a medium-sized graph. Graphviz will handle it but networkx's matplotlib drawing engine may have problems.  It all depends on the connectedness of the graph.